# How to make cut/copy/paste in GVim on Ubuntu work with Ctrl+X,Ctrl+C,Ctrl+V?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-editing, gvim

By default, the cut/copy/paste short-cuts in GVim on Ubuntu are:

```
 Cut    "+x
 Copy   "+y
 Paste  "+gP
```

I would like to use control key combos in GVim, like I use in Firefox and othe gnome applications. How do I configure GVim to work like other Gnome apps?

Comment: To avoid conflicts with default vim keys, opt for Ctrl+Shift+Key instead of Ctrl+Key

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `_vimrc` or `.vimrc`

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

But beware, visual mode is then CTRL-Q instead of CTRL-V.

For an overview what mswin.vim does see the
[mswin.vim sourcode](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/mswin.vim).
It is commented very well and if some command is unclear you can easily look it up in
vim's help.

Here is a quick overview compiled from the source:

> - backspace and cursor keys wrap to previous/next line
> - CTRL-X and SHIFT-Del are Cut
> - CTRL-C and CTRL-Insert are Copy
> - CTRL-V and SHIFT-Insert are Paste
> - Use CTRL-Q to do what CTRL-V used to do
> - Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
> - CTRL-Z is Undo; not in cmdline though
> - CTRL-Y is Redo (although not repeat); not in cmdline though
> - Alt-Space is System menu
> - CTRL-A is Select all
> - CTRL-Tab is Next window
> - CTRL-F4 is Close window

At Nippysaurus' request:
I put following in my .gvimrc to show Ctrl-V besides Paste in the menu:

```
unmenu! Edit.Paste
aunmenu Edit.Paste
nnoremenu 20.360 &Edit.&Paste<Tab>Ctrl-V        "+gP
cnoremenu    &Edit.&Paste<Tab>Ctrl-V        <C-R>+
```

I didn't test it thoroughly, just a quick check if it did what I expected. Works for me, hope it works for you;-)

Comment: I understand and appreciate the points that Manni and Peter Thorin made in the comments of Peter Thorin's answer. My take is that I learned GVim on Windows, as a notepad replacement, and I want less friction. Thanks Ludwig

Comment: Is there a way to change the menu shortcut text to match the new shortcut keys?

Comment: @Nippysaurus: I'd tried it with menutrans in .gvimrc. Didn't get it to work, will have another look at it in the evening...

Comment: @Nippysaurus: Added a possible solution to my answer, see above.

Comment: With this, VIM deserves a second chance!

Comment: But this doesn't work for **GVim**, only for Vim!

Comment: It looks like `mswin.vim` already has a `behave mswin` call.  Is it necessary to call this again in my own `_vimrc`?

Comment: @NathanFriend Ditto. It works even without `behave mswin`, at least on my system with Vim 8.0.

Answer (score 59):

If you want Cut/Copy/Paste to work using the "standard" hotkeys, but you don't want to change any of the other configuration options in gvim, try do add the following to `~/.vimrc`.

```
vmap <C-c> "+yi
vmap <C-x> "+c
vmap <C-v> c<ESC>"+p
imap <C-v> <C-r><C-o>+
```

Paste only works in Visual and insert mode, so you don't have to worry about the conflict with Ctrl-V and blockwise Visual Mode.  This isn't a problem, because Copy and Cut put you into insert mode, so you can immediately paste afterwards.  If you try it out you'll find that it feels completely natural.

I came up with this configuration after several iterations of tweaking, and I think it's "perfect" now.  If you're even a little bit dissatisfied with your current copy/paste configuration, try this out and I bet you'll love it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: After some experiments and consultation of `:help i_ctrl-r_ctrl-o`, I decided to change `imap <C-v> <ESC>"+pa` to `imap <C-v> <C-r><C-o>+`; this works as expected when the cursor is to the left of the first character of a line, and it most closely imitates the "standard" behavior.

Comment: I'm thinking about changing `<C-v>`to shift+insert that seems to be alot faster on my machine. But in the middle of a project and don't feel like restarting vim right now. Just sharing

Comment: You are awesome =)

Comment: works like a charm.

Comment: perfect.........

Answer (score 9):

If you want to maintain the normal vim behavior but also allow for less cumbersome use of the system clipboard, see [Accessing the system clipboard](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip984). If you would like gvim to use the system clipboard as its default buffer (so any `x`, `y`, `p`, etc. command uses the clipboard) then add the following line to your vimrc:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

I personally use the buffers far more within vim than between vim and the system; so I'd rather have a slightly more cumbersome shortcut than have my system clipboard constantly clobbered. But it's nice that the option is there for those who would prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

I would think you can add this with the :imap command (tried it just with Ctrl+X in Windows which worked, pressing ctrl+c seems to cancel the command though so you might have to do it in vimrc).

```
:imap <C-X> "+x
:imap <C-C> "+y 
:imap <C-V> "+gP
```

If you add it to your ~/.vimrc you just need to remove the : in front of imap.

imap only adds the bindings in insert mode, so you might want to change it to just map or something else. Look into `:help mapmode` to learn more about remapping and unmapping stuff.

Good luck!

Comment: This should do a bit of the trick. But it is a bad idea to do that. Ctrl-V should go into visual mode, Ctrl-C will cancel any commands. And the trick will only work on your system; on a different machine, you will be lost.

Comment: I agree in part with that it is a bad idea, I wouldn't want to use it myself, but if you are a casual gvim user only, then you would probably not miss the bindings you remove anyway.

Comment: The why use gvim in the first place? How long will you stay a casual user?

Comment: I don't think it's such a bad idea. People are used to Ctrl+X etc. and there are billions other reasons to use vim.