# Vim - Move selection up/down with Ctrl+Shift+Arrow

Tags: vim

I want to move a selection up/down with Ctrl+Shift+Arrow, similar like in other editors. What I currently have in my .vimrc is the following:

```
" from https://superuser.com/a/825561
:behave mswin
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
:smap <Del> <C-g>"_d
:smap <C-c> <C-g>y
:smap <C-x> <C-g>x
:imap <C-v> <Esc>pi
:smap <C-v> <C-g>p
:smap <Tab> <C-g>1>
:smap <S-Tab> <C-g>1<

" from https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2682
nnoremap <C-S-Up> :m-2<CR>
nnoremap <C-S-Down> :m+<CR>
inoremap <C-S-Up> <Esc>:m-2<CR>
inoremap <C-S-Down> <Esc>:m+<CR>

" enable syntax highlighting
syntax enable

" show line numbers
set number

" set tabs to have 4 spaces
set ts=4

" indent when moving to the next line while writing code
set autoindent

" expand tabs into spaces
set expandtab

" when using the >> or << commands, shift lines by 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4

" show a visual line under the cursor's current line
set cursorline

" show the matching part of the pair for [] {} and ()
set showmatch

" enable all Python syntax highlighting features
let python_highlight_all = 1

" remove wrong indentation when pasting
augroup auto_comment
    au!
    au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o
augroup END
```

This works fine to move a line with Ctrl+Shift+ArrowUp/Down, but if I select text and then try to move the selection, only the current line will be moved and the selection gets unselected. I did not find help by googling. Help is appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add to `.vimrc` to move selection with `ctrl + shift + up`, `ctrl + shift + down`:

```
vnoremap <C-S-Up>   :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <C-S-Down> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
```

Answer (score 1):

For visual moving, you could use theses bindings :

```
xnoremap <C-S-Up> xkP`[V`]
xnoremap <C-S-Down> xp`[V`]
xnoremap <C-S-Left> <gv
xnoremap <C-S-Right> >gv
```

I personally prefer `CTRL+hjkl` than reaching the arrow keys, but use whatever keys suits you best.

Now, for moving the current line while in insert mode, I use this function which moves n lines up or down. Binding it to `-1` and `+1` works great.

```
function! MoveLineAndInsert(n)       " -x=up x lines; +x=down x lines
    let n_move = (a:n < 0 ? a:n-1 : '+'.a:n)
    let pos = getcurpos()
    try         " maybe out of range
        exe ':move'.n_move
        call setpos('.', [0,pos[1]+a:n,pos[2],0])
    finally
        startinsert
    endtry
endfunction
inoremap <C-S-Up> <Esc>`^:silent! call MoveLineAndInsert(-1)<CR>
inoremap <C-S-Down> <Esc>`^:silent! call MoveLineAndInsert(+1)<CR>
```

The `try`/`finally` block and the `` `^:silent! `` part of the mapping are here to make it gracefully degrading on the edges of the buffer.

### Edit

For this to work,

- the `set nocompatible` option must be set
- `behave mswin` should be removed in order to use `<C-S-{Arrow}>`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435611/select-word-in-vim-with-ctrlshiftarrow/31444283#31444283)
- for Tmux users, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/402084/1058201)

Comment: That actually does not solve the question. Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down selects lines instead of moving them.

Comment: @MichaelH. in which modes does this happens ? `xnoremap` is for moving while in visual mode and inoremap is for insert mode. Maybe there is something in your .vimrc that prevent something to work as expected ? Shouldn't happen because of the `nore`cursive maps. For me, in linux, gnome-terminal, outside of tmux, it works well even if my .vimrc only contains theses mappings with `set nocompatible`.

Comment: I'll share all of my .vimrc

Comment: I guess you are running in Vi-compatible mode. Run `set compatible?` to verify. I suggest you turn of the this option off with `set nocompatible` before any mappings for a better Vim experience. From `:h compatible`, it is automaticaly turned off if you use your own .vimrc instead of the systemwide one. I wouldn't know how to answer your question with `compatible` turned on.

Comment: I moved the `set nocompatible` call to the beginning and inserted your two code blocks from the answer after my first block of mappings. Still, Ctrl+Shift+Arrow changes the selections (just like Ctrl+Arrow) instead of moving the selection. I'm sorry, I don't really understand what all this options in my .vimrc do...

Comment: It seems to be because of the `:behave mswin`, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435611/select-word-in-vim-with-ctrlshiftarrow/31444283#31444283) which have very good advices. Also, in your first block, I strongly recommend you **only** keep the clipboard setting and change the `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>` mappings to `xnoremap <Tab> >gv` and `xnoremap <S-Tab> <gv`, and remove thoses `:` at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Add to `.vimrc` to move selection with `ctrl + shift + up`, `ctrl + shift + down`:

```
noremap <C-S-Up>     :m -2 <enter>
noremap <C-S-Down>   :m +1 <enter>
inoremap <C-S-Up>    <esc> :m -2 <enter>
inoremap <C-S-Down>  <esc> :m +1 <enter>
```

Add to `.vimrc` to move selection with `ctrl + shift + k`, `ctrl + shift + j`:

```
noremap <C-S-k>      :m -2 <enter>
noremap <C-S-j>      :m +1 <enter>
inoremap <C-S-k>    <esc> :m -2 <enter>
inoremap <C-S-j>    <esc> :m +1 <enter>
```