# Copying/Pasting in VIM without overwriting register

Tags: vim

Haven't been able to figure this out...

So I usually like to select a word (say, `albatross`) and copy it to a register using <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd>, which–as I understand it–copies it into the `*` register.

Then I want to paste it back over another word (`sparrow`), so I'll do <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>.

But often I'll want to paste the original word (`albatross`) over yet another word (`osprey`), but when I try to repeat my past commands, the pasted value comes out as `sparrow`, not `albatross`. This, I know, is because when the text is deleted before being pasted, it's copied into the `*` register, overwriting `albatross` with `sparrow`.

I thought I could work around this by using named registers, so I tried copying with <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> and pasting with <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>, but that just reproduces my original problem with the `*` register using the `"1` register.

To all you VIM ninjas out there, what am I doing wrong? I'd like to be able to quickly yank some arbitrary text (preferably using the `*` register, as it saves me two keystrokes) and paste that original value `n` times afterwards at any point in the document.

How is something like this done efficiently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace-paste yanked text in vim without yanking the deleted lines?](https://superuser.com/questions/321547/how-do-i-replace-paste-yanked-text-in-vim-without-yanking-the-deleted-lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `"a` to `"z` (named) registers, instead of the numbered registers, which stores previous deletes automatically.

Comment: Ahh, thanks; I didn't realize there was a difference between numbered and named registers.

Comment: Btw, `:registers` gives you the contents of all registers, can be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The `0` register holds the last text yanked, so once you yank some text, you should be able to paste it over and over again with `"0p`. For more about this, see

```
:help quote0
```

Comment: Also helpful, but `"a` is easier to type than `"0`. :)

Comment: Yeah, but with `"a` you also have to yank to `"a`, whereas with `"0` you can just yank to the default register.

Comment: Very true, but it's less muscle-memory training for me to navigate `"a` for two extra keystrokes than it is to reach up to `"0` even once. Still, useful info. Thanks!

Comment: @garyjohn great tip, didn't know that.