# How can I check if the cursor is at the end of a line?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, macvim, vim-plugins

Gentleman,

Simple question about Vim!

How can I check if the cursor is at the end of a line using a function in vimrc?

[]'s

Comment: Why do you need to know? What are you trying to accomplish? Sometimes it is easier to force end of line, or use a command that doesn't care about end of line, or something else. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve, instead of your assumed solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need a function to determine this, but you could wrap the following test in a function if you needed to. That would depend on what you are trying to do and what you need from the function.

The `col()` function returns the column of its argument. The last column of a row is `col("$")-1` and the cursor column is `col(".")`, so

```
echo col(".") == col("$")-1
```

will echo`1` when the cursor is at the last column and `0` otherwise.

See:

```
:help col()
```

Comment: There's an edge case to consider: on an empty line, `col(".")` returns `1` and `col("$")` also returns `1`. So you'd probably want to check if `col(".") >= col("$") - 1`.

Comment: This also doesn't work if the character under the cursor is multi-byte, e.g. `U+2124` (ℤ) is three bytes, so if it's the last character on a line, `col('.') + 3 == col('$')`